# Laravel Social Authentication Without Reloading Client Application(website)

Tags: facebook, laravel-5, twitter-oauth

I have a Workflow application(website) using canjs. The various steps(pages) are preloaded. A user is allowed to explore the app without login. However if the user wishes to save the workflow, they must login. Alternatively the user can login at any of the steps in the workflow.
The application has a provision for users to login using Facebook and Twitter. 
The backend consists of Laravel and Socialite[link](https://github.com/laravel/socialite)package take care of the login process.

As Facebook and Twitter use OAUTH the login work flow is as follows :

1. Client calls a login init route.
2. The route redirects to a login page of the social login provider(FB or twitter)
3. User Authenticates/Authorises your app
4. The user is redirected to a success route (say /success_callback) on your app. At this point we can use Socialite package to get the user information.

The issue I'm facing is that I don't want to reload the APP on the client browser. So how to inform the client from /success_callback if the user has logged in or not, etc.

Comment: For Facebook, you should use the JS SDK to handle login – then you can have that working purely client-side without any extra effort.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to give a couple of social options and wanted to have a common/similar. Twitter does not have a client side sdk I suppose.

Comment: Well if you want to go with the redirect flow, then you could open that in a popup yourself, and when it redirects back to your site in there, you send the necessary data to the parent window, and then close the popup.